# Manage huge data to insert into sqlite database for an android app

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

i,m making an android app which deals with counter information of bus train and plain in Bangladesh. I want to store those information into sqlite database. But i can't figure it out what will be the best approach to store those huge amount of info in a tabular form. I mean m i need to code all the data into my src file? OR is there any graphical UI (like MySql database) of this database to write the data into table without coding it?
  i don't sure that you understand my question. If you not then please ask what point i make confusion. Advance thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i can't figure it out what will be the best approach to store those huge amount of info in a tabular form

[SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

> I mean m i need to code all the data into my src file?

Usually, you'd use an existing API to read the data you want from an existing database somewhere (in this case, often the transport department), and then programmatically iterate over it and store it locally

> OR is there any graphical UI (like MySql database) of this database to write the data into table without coding it?

1. MySQL is not a graphical program. It is a database. You get various graphical interfaces for it, but on its own it isn't one.
2. MySQL doesn't work on Android
3. You can write a simple script or app easily enough to allow you to enter the data using a UI

Comment: You don,t get my question...any way thanks for the answer. :)